# select count by undetermined value

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I want counting count of cities divided by countries

```
TABLE : WORLD

_CITY _COUNTRY
seoul korea
busan korea
daegu korea
ulsan korea
tokyo japan
osaka japan
```

Using SQLite on Android Studio

I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT _CITY, (SELECT COUNT (_COUNTRY) FROM WORLD WHERE _COUNTRY = 'japan') AS _COUNT FROM WORLD
```

But I don't want to be specific because I want to know the number of each country.

```
SELECT DISTINCT _CITY, (SELECT COUNT (_COUNTRY) FROM WORLD WHERE _COUNTRY = ?????) AS _COUNT FROM WORLD
```

I expect the output to be

```
_COUNTRY _COUNT
korea    4
japan    2
```

actual output

```
_COUNTRY _COUNT
korea    4
japan    4
```

What subquery should I put instead of WHERE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below- using a group by with aggregation

```
select _COUNTRY,count(*) as _COUNT
from tablename
group by _COUNTRY
```

Answer (score 0):

use group by country, no need any subquery

```
select _COUNTRY,count(*) _COUNT from table
group by _COUNTRY
```